# How to disable the audio output of Gnome Boxes (or at least mute all sound)?

Tags: gnome, audio, wayland, gnome-boxes

Most desktop environments and distros use various alert sounds, can be distracting when you have a high-end sound system connected to the computer and some ~0 dBFS bell jingle or a generic error sound plays.

At the time **I don't need any audio in my virtual machines** — it's preferred to entirely disable the sound processing, if possible. I'd appreciate not having to ever configure the audio setting in a fresh VM (be it alsamixer, pactl for Pulseaudio or DE settings).

The Gnome volume mixer (settings → sound → volume levels) doesn't appear to save the muted state even for one VM.

Comment: If needed, for instance [Wikimedia offers suitable sample media files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Media_(audio_and_video)).

Comment: I wonder whether under-the-hood fiddling with the VMs would allow you to simply remove the sound device from the virtual hardware. Then again, if you actually need to do such a thing, maybe leave Boxes behind and directly go for `virt-manager`.